# Multipart: Unexpected end of form with nestjs

Tags: javascript, nestjs, multipartform-data, multer, interceptor

```
  @Post()
  @Roles('USER', 'ADMIN')
  @ApiBody({
    description: 'Upload file',
    type: 'object',
    required: true,
  })
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
  async uploadFile(
    @UploadedFile()
    file: Express.Multer.File,
  ) {
    console.log(file);
    await this.uploadService.uploadToFile(file);
    return { message: 'File uploaded successfully' };
 }
```

i am trying to create an endpoint to upload files with nestjs, when i test this on postman with form data and setting the key value to file i keep getting this error

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "Multipart: Unexpected end of form"
}
```

i tried different images, and i tried to send the request without the FileInterceptor the file gets logged but as an a normal object

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'pre-order-now.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: './uploads/',
  filename: 'name.png',
  path: 'uploads/pre-order-now.png',
  size: 1127
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was an incorrectly configured midlware that caused a problem with threads, I advise you to check your main ts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).